# AVAudioRecorder memory leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, avaudiorecorder

I'm developing an iPhone 3.1.3 app.

I have the following code in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

if (recorder == nil)
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];

    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 
                                                  target: self
                                                selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:)
                                                userInfo: nil 
                                                 repeats: YES];
```

Note: I check if `recorder` has been created before create a new one with this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if (recorder == nil)
        recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
```

When I move from this ViewController to another ViewController I do this:

```
[levelTimer invalidate];
levelTimer = nil;
[recorder pause];
```

And finally, I release `recorder` on `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if (recorder != nil) {
        [recorder release];
        }
}
```

Running it with Xcode option 'Run with Performance Tool', looking for Leaks, I'm getting leaks with `AVAudioRecorder`.

The program will go from this first ViewController to a second ViewController. And then, when user wants, it will go from second ViewController to first ViewController and it will run first code I've added.

Is there a memory problem? Do you know a better way to do that? I want avoid been recording while user is in second viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you releasing `recorder`. If you're releasing it in the `dealloc` method, or not releasing it at all, you may have a leak, assuming the code you've pasted above is triggered in `viewDidLoad` or similar. `recorder` will get a new `AVAudioRecorder` assigned to it every time the view reloads, but will only be released once (when the view controller is dealloc'd).

Comment: I've updated my question with more details. I check if recorder == nil to create a new one, so I don't think I'm creating one on every view reloads.